TypeScript Error: 'File is not under rootDir' despite correct directory structure
i am learning react and i am fairly new to it , I have been coding along a youtube video
but i am getting some error in my server side program and I suspect due to which i can't make directories in my server(mongoDB)
Here is my type script file
import express, { Request,Response } from "express";
import FinancialRecordModel from "../schema/financial-record"; //this is where I am getting an error 

const router = express.Router();


router.get("/getAllByUserId/:userId",async(req :Request ,res : Response)=>{
    try{
        const userId = req.params.userId;
        const records = await FinancialRecordModel.find({userId : userId});
        if(records.length===0)
            {
                return res.status(404).send("N0 RECORDS FOUND.");
            }   
            res.status(200).send(records);
        }catch(err){    
            res.status(500).send(err);
    }
});


router.post("/",async(req :Request ,res : Response)=>{
    try{
        const newRecordBody = req.body;
        const newRecord = new FinancialRecordModel(newRecordBody);
        const savedRecord = await newRecord.save();

        res.status(200).send(savedRecord);
        }catch(err){    
            res.status(500).send(err);
    }
});

router.put("/:id",async(req :Request ,res : Response)=>{
    try{
        const id =req.params.id;
        const newRecordBody = req.body;
        
        const record = await FinancialRecordModel.findById(
            id,
            newRecordBody,
            {
                new : true,
            }
        );
        
        if(!record) return res.status(404).send();

        res.status(200).send(record);
        }catch(err){    
            res.status(500).send(err);
    }
});

router.delete("/:id",async(req :Request ,res : Response)=>{
    try{
        const id =req.params.id;
        const record = await FinancialRecordModel.findByIdAndDelete(id);
         
        if(!record) return res.status(404).send();

        res.status(200).send(record);
        }catch(err){    
            res.status(500).send(err);
    }
});
export default router;



File 'c:/Users/Shashwat/Desktop/HTML/practice/React/Personal Finace Tracker/server/src/schema/financial-record.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'c:/Users/Shashwat/Desktop/HTML/practice/React/Personal Finace Tracker/server/src/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
The file is in the program because:
Imported via "../schema/financial-record" from file 'c:/Users/Shashwat/Desktop/HTML/practice/React/Personal Finace Tracker/server/src/routes/financial-records.ts'
Matched by default include pattern '**/*'ts(6059)

this is the error i am getting
i tried changing
"rootDir": "./src", 

in my tsconfig.json file but it didn't do anything
